How to expand C drive by default whenever I open explorer?
Is it possible to made windows explorer expand folders by default?
I want to see this: C: drive expanded whenever I open explorer.

Pinned quick access shortcuts suck cause expand to current folder doesn't work on them.
Right click menu also doesn't work normally for folders opened via quick access.
If I have to navigate via C drive every time, it would be great to have a set of folders expanded by default instead.

Create a desktop shortcut: C:\Windows\explorer.exe c:

@DrMoishePippik thanks, but that sadly doesn't cause the folder to be expanded, you have to then open a subfolder for it to expand properly :(

In Explorer, there is a setting to automatically expand (or not) the current folder: https://www.elevenforum.com/t/turn-on-or-off-expand-folder-in-navigation-pane-of-file-explorer-in-windows-11.2544/ This has already been answered here and elsewhere.

@DrMoishePippik yes I know. It does not work in certain cases, such as the one mentioned in my original post, and in the case of the desktop shortcut you suggested.

@zoaha The Navigation Pane can be configured to expand to the currently selected directory, but AFAIK cannot be configured to expand the root of a single drive when that drive has not been selected in Explorer (even then, upon opening a subfolder, it'll continue to expand in a tree). This is by design and operating as intended.

The solution is to set the default folder to C: instead of This PC using the registry.
Create a .reg file using the following code:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\shell\OpenNewWindow\command]
@="Explorer \"C:\""
"DelegateExecute"=""

You can also choose a different folder if you want.
Source: elevenforum.com

This would always open Explorer to the root of C:, which seems like an inconvenience in general, and when navigating out of the root of C:, has it been verified the Navigation Pane will still show the root of C: expanded (I'm not currently on a machine I can test)? A workaround for the former could be to create a separate Explorer shortcut/.cmd to use, but AFAIK the latter will still be an issue since this is how Explorer and the Windows Shell is programmed by design AFAIK

Why would it be an inconvenience when that's the very thing the OP was asking for? C: remains expanded when navigating somewhere else, yes. Why use a shortcut when win+e works fine? There is a limitation however when using an external drive. The external drives appears twice, once under "this PC" and once on its own. The Windows 11 explorer is horrible. It's baffling to see how incompetent Microsoft employees can be.

The OP is asking about how to expand the Navigation Pane - this answer causes Explorer to always open to the root of C: within  Explorer, which has nothing to do with the Navigation Pane. The Navigation Pane can be configured to expand to the currently selected directory, but AFAIK cannot be configured to expand the root of a single drive when that drive has not been selected in Explorer (even then, upon opening a subfolder, it'll continue to expand in a tree and will close out of the tree and open a new tree as soon as a different drive/namespace is selected).
